# Why is my css and js not enqueued until footer?

Tags: actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
function ( ) {
    global $post,$pageparent;
    if(in_array($pageparent, array($post->ID,$post->post_parent))){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'products_pages', urlto.'products_pages.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script('tooltipster',    urlto.'js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js',   array( 'jquery' ));
    }
} 
, 1, 0 );
```

I've tried hooking this to many different hooks like wp, etc.  I cant figure out where to hook so that A. The $post is set up and 2. the style and script get included in the header.  With this, they are included in the footer.

It works in the footer, at least the css does, I havent tried this script yet.  But, best practices and all.

Comment: `urlto` is not set.

Comment: What is `global $pageparent`? I can't seem to find any reference to that in WordPress, is that something you set?

Comment: $pageparent is just an ID that I set outside the action.  It's nothing to do with the question.  either is urlto.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to add styles and scripts to a single post. The best way to achieve this is to make use of the conditional tag [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) With that you target specific single posts or all single posts.

Styles should always be loaded in the header. `<link>` tags outside the `<head></head>` tags are invalid HTML. You should check [this recent post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/162150/31545) on this subject.

On the other hand, scripts can be loaded in the footer of header, though many agree that it should be loaded in the footer.

I would also replace your `$priority` of `1` with `PHP_INT_MAX` to load your custom styles and scripts after all the other styles and scripts have loaded. This will avoid that your custom scripts and styles will be overwritten by other scripts and styles

Just one note, I don't know what does `urlto` in your code means, but I should accept that you know that this should either be `get_template_directory_uri()` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` depending on parent theme or child theme and I also accept that you have changed this to make your code simpler for the sake of the question

This is an idea of how your code should look like:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
function ( ) {
    if( is_single() ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'products_pages', urlto.'/products_pages.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script('tooltipster',    urlto.'/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js',   array( 'jquery' ));
    }
} 
, PHP_INT_MAX, 0 );
```

References:

- [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)
- [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)
- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

**EDIT**

From the comments to this answer, it seems that your method works. I have one concern though targeting a post through `$post` variable. If you specifically need to target justy the single view pages, you are going to run into some issues.

You have to remember, on any page, `$post` will hold the value of the last post in the loop. What this means is, if , for  instance, the specific post you need to target is the last post on the home page, all changes will affect the home page too, and not just the single page view of the post.

That is why you should make use of `is_single()` to target single posts, and not `$post` global

Comment: You could go even further and add a at the top of the function `global $post` then in your if statement, if OP wanted to only add this on a single post you could say: `if( isset($post) && $post->ID == 123)`.

Comment: AFAIK, `$post` is set by `the_post()`during the loop.

Comment: I've never had a problem accessing it via `wp_enqueu_scripts`. I can access it after `wp_head()` in the header file. I'm not entirely sure when or where `global $post` is actually set but from just running around printing the global post, it seems like it's set way before the actual loop. Even if I don't have a loop on a page, `global $post` still seems to be set.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I must still do some tests, but I have one concern that I just thought of, you have to remember, on any page, `$post` will have the value of the last post on that particular page. This will be problematic if you want to specifically target a post's single page. If that post is the last post on a post page, you changes will affect that post page too, not just that specific post's single page

Comment: See my update. This should explain it a bit more

Comment: If you're targeting a Single Post (single.php) then it should be the first post on the page to load if my theory of `$post` being loaded in / before the header is valid. If global `$post` is changed at a later point, `wp_enqueue_scripts` has already run and the change wouldn't affect our enqueueing. Granted, if you're running it on `index.php`, any archive template, or taxonomy `global $post` will actually be set to the first post found in the query, at least at the time of enqueueing. So it should still hold valid for both pages and any single post / cpt.

Answer (score 0):

> I cant figure out where to hook so that A. The $post is set up and 2.
>   the style and script get included in the header.

Those two things are mutually exclusive. The global $post won't be set up until the main Loop starts, which is well after the header has already been output.

Edit for comments clarification:

Again, the actual `global $post` isn't set until the Loop starts. So if you need the actual contents of that variable, you have to wait until then.

But functions like `is_single()` are only checking if the current query is for a single post or not. It doesn't depend on the actual contents of the post.

The functions called "Conditional Tags" are not looking at the actual $post from the Loop, they are looking at the query. Now, the query has run by this point, so the data is in memory, it's just not in the global $post. So, if you wanted to check if this is the single post for the post named "Example", then yes, `is_single('Example')` will work just fine at this early point in the code.

The `global $post` is not set up yet. But the data does exist in the main $wp_query and yes, it can be read and accessed in various ways by the time the theme template has loaded. And yes, you can base conditions like loading stuff on it.

But it's not the global $post, and it has not gone through the Loop, and thus it hasn't gone through the assorted WP filter functions yet. So if you do something like look ahead to the content in the post, then what you get will be straight data from the database, not the filtered pretty data that WordPress produces. Shortcodes won't be processed. Plugins won't have filtered the post and added their magic. Embedded videos won't be embedded yet. That sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, so this is just the way it has to be, then?  Is there a problem with inlcuding js and css in the footer? FOUC?

Comment: If you're absolutely dependent on enqueueing only for certain posts, then yeah, that's how it has to be. Nothing wrong with putting JS/CSS in the footer, as such. Or, change your script and styles to be on all pages instead of only some of them. You can use is_single() and other template tags as well, if you want to limit it to certain types of pages, like single post pages and not archives or the main blog page.

Comment: I'm just tryna not include css/js everywhere when only these few pages need it.  So, is_single() will work before  $post is setup? That seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Edited my post to answer your question because comments are not big enough.

Comment: @Otto it looks like the `global $post` is set up before the actually main loop. So you should still be able to get it in the `header.php`. So saying that `global $post` is only accessible during [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) is incorrect.

Comment: @Otto, Ahh... I see!  $wp_query->post Seems to be populated before action:'wp'.  And I dont need the filters, just the ID and or post_parent.  This may solve the question, yes?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee The `global $post` is set up when the function called `the_post()` is called. This is normally done at the beginning of The Loop. Some plugins and other things may prematurely run a small Loop to setup the $post variable early, but you cannot depend on this being set properly. I am uncertain whether $wp_query->post will be properly set, but I doubt it is reliable before the Loop starts. However, using the Conditional Tags functions such as is_single() should work properly.

Comment: @Otto Looks like global $post is set much earlier - [See Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165641/when-and-where-is-global-post-set-and-available/165736#165736). So for pages and single posts it should still be reliable but for archives and anything that display more than 1 post, it won't be reliable as `global $post` will be set to the first post in the loop.

Comment: It's still unreliable. Many plugins and themes and such will run their own Loops at various points, changing that value. Until you start a Loop, you can't be certain what it is.

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters of the [enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function is the `$in_footer`

take a look of the function usage arguments:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer )
```

So to add your script(or css) to the header instead of footer you should try something like:

```
wp_enqueue_script('tooltipster', urlto.'/jsjquery.tooltipster.min.js',   array( 'jquery' ),'',false);
```

Generally scripts are better to be loaded at the bottom while css is usually found on top,
consider that if your script is jquery dependent you're probably  better off setting  $in_footer value to true,

Comment: $in_footer is default to false.  Therefore, I am wanting it to be in the header, by not specifying.  However, I am too late.

Comment: Setting the jquery dependency might lead to loading the script after jquery is loaded, even is $in_footer is set to false .. you need to analize your source to see where the scripts are placed, consider that the hooks are wp_head(in header.php) and wp_footer (footer.php)

Comment: Good guess, but jquery is loaded in the head.  And that wouldnt account for the css.

Comment: It happend to me once